# generate unique username (omniauth + devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have an app with user authentication with devise + omniauth.

In my model that username in my app is **unique**. I dont want duplicate username in my app.

Some users in facebook has not a defined username  in his profile.

I want generate an unique username if the user has not username defined in facebook.

For example for generate password I have this:

```
:password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
```

How can I generate a unique username for my app if the facebook user has not username in facebook?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a part of email before the @ sign and add there smth like user_id, or just take the email itself. Or you can combine somehow the first and last names from the fb response.

Comment: Thank you, can you write a example? Thank you @alony ;). I had thought something like: `user.username = "user_#{user.id.to_s}"`. I'm using mongoid. my ids are type `"4f72ee7e1d41c87cb1000001"`. I dont know if my fix its correct!

Comment: I always do like this:
`user.username = user.email[/^[^@]*/]`, it looks nice but potentially can repeat. In your case you can do like this: `user.username = "#{user.email[/^[^@]*/]}_#{user.id.to_s[0..5]}"` - taking first 6 just not to make it too long :)

Comment: Thank you it does works fine  for me :D. But with 0..5 its possible can repeat?. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, possible, but there are not many chances to get 2 people with equal email names and equal first 6 ID signs :) Anyway it's up to you, to use the whole id is just fine

Comment: Thank you. I dont want have problem in the app, so I think that I will deploy with full id. It is more effective but more ugly :(. Thank you @alony

Answer (score 12):

You can create a nice readable username  (eg generated from the first part of the email) and then ensure it is unique by adding numbers until it is.  eg

```
#in User
def get_unique_login
  login_part = self.email.split("@").first
  new_login = login_part.dup 
  num = 2
  while(User.find_by_login(new_login).count > 0)
    new_login = "#{login_part}#{num}"
    num += 1
  end
  new_login
end
```

One problem here is that someone could potentially bag that login inbetween you getting it and you saving it.  So, maybe it's best to combine it into a before_create filter:

```
#in User
before_create :ensure_login_uniqueness

def ensure_login_uniqueness 
  if self.login.blank? || User.find_by_login(self.login).count > 0
    login_part = self.email.split("@").first
    new_login = login_part.dup 
    num = 2
    while(User.find_by_login(new_login).count > 0)
      new_login = "#{login_part}#{num}"
      num += 1
    end
    self.login = new_login
  end
end
```

Comment: Should not the while loop include num += 1 at the end?

Comment: Thank a lot! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i created Login with combination of first name and last name field.. Improvements on this code is welcome.

```
 before_create :ensure_login_uniqueness

  def ensure_login_uniqueness 
    if self.login.blank? 
      self.name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
      firstnamePart = self.first_name.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
      lastnamePart = self.last_name.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '') 
      login_part = firstnamePart+lastnamePart 
      new_login = login_part.dup 
      num = 1
      while(User.where(:login => new_login).count > 0)
        new_login = "#{login_part}#{num}"
        num += 1
      end
      self.login = new_login
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey Dave, could you possibly help me out with this? I tried adding this into my user model but I'm getting the error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.login' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`login` = 'bobweir'

Comment: I also tried a more simplified version, you can check out my post about it here if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793011/generating-meaningful-usernames-in-devise

Comment: @thesowismine have you added a column named "login" in your migration file for user table. Adding it will solve your error. :)

Comment: I figured it out a little while ago and yea that as it! I was just getting confused since I thought that was a method... Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

It did not work for me,but change:

```
while(User.find_by_login(new_login).count > 0)
```

to

```
while(User.where(login: new_login).count > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my methods that I use for Facebook

```
  def ensure_username_uniqueness
    self.username ||= self.email.split("@").first
    num = 2
    until(User.find_by(username: self.username).nil?)
      self.username = "#{username_part}#{num}"
      num += 1
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = auth.info.name.downcase.gsub(" ", "")
      user.username = user.username[0..29] if user.username.length > 30
      user.ensure_username_uniqueness
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how you can generate "username" from "full name"

```
  def self.generate_username(full_name)
    generated = ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(full_name) # change ñ => n
                            .downcase              # only lower case
                            .strip                 # remove spaces around the string
                            .gsub(/[^a-z]/, '_')   # any character that is not a letter or a number will be _
                            .gsub(/\A_+/, '')      # remove underscores at the beginning
                            .gsub(/_+\Z/, '')      # remove underscores at the end
                            .gsub(/_+/, '_')

    taken_usernames = User
                        .where("username LIKE ?", "#{generated}%")
                        .pluck(:username)

    # username if it's free
    return generated unless taken_usernames.include?(generated)

    count = 2
    while true
      # username_2, username_3...
      new_username = "#{generated}_#{count}"
      return new_username if ! taken_usernames.include?(new_username)
      count += 1
    end
  end
```