# generating meaningful usernames in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to have my app automatically generate usernames to be used as the url. Typically they will be the users first and last name added together however when there already exists a user with the same first and last name it will append a number to the name that increases for each.

This is the method i created:

```
def full_name
  first_name + ' ' + last_name
end

def user_name
  t_user_name = first_name.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '') + last_name.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
  user_name = t_user_name
  num = 1
  while User.find_by_user_name(user_name).count > 0
    num += 1
    user_name = "#{t_user_name}#{num}"
  end
end
```

I'm currently getting the error:

```
undefined method `find_by_user_name'
```

**Which i thought would work automatically?**

I was also trying to examples shown in this post:

[generate unique username (omniauth + devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905418/generate-unique-username-omniauth-devise)

but I kept getting the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.login' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`login` = 'bobweir'
```

Even though I added

```
t.string :login,          null: false, default: ""
```

to the users table

edit2: schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150611033237) do

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name",             limit: 255
  t.string   "last_name",              limit: 255
  t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at",                                      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                      null: false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
```

end

Comment: Please show us your schema.rb file.

Comment: Added it, and just realized that rake db:migrate is deleting the user_name column that I added.... Is this the issue?

Comment: You have neither a `user_name` nor a `login` column.

Comment: Ok I have succesfully added user_name to the schema.rb, but now im getting undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is your `user_name` method a method on the `Users` model?  Think about that for a second....

Comment: Yes! but I'm still lost... sorry! Im fairly new to rails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80338/discussion-between-daiku-and-thesowismine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails achieves *find_by_sth* magic by inferring an attribute name in your method call, thus returning an ActiveRecordRelation.

As you have no *user_name* attribute in your model, Active Record will not be able to perform a search on it (just imagine it has to be translated into an SQL query).

On the other hand, I'd re-think the logic of your *user_name* method if I were you. Consider persisting the user_name on your database.

By the way, in the second error you mention, notice that the example you have is working with a *login* attribute, which you simply don't have.

Comment: Thanks! But yea im just now realizing that... What exactly is their login attribute for though?

Comment: Oh, i think i got it, is it just the user_name itself, and if it is left empty than in creates a new one?

Comment: Their *login* attribute holds the equivalent to your *user_name* attribute. That is: He has a User model, which can generate a unique username by calling *get_unique_login* (notice how he's not overriding *login* accessor).

By the way, I'd recommend setting that behaviour as a User (class) responsability, not as an instance method.

Comment: Ok thanks alot! So is it just the "self" that makes it a class method then? So the other examples are class methods?

Comment: There are several ways to define a class method in Ruby. One of them is prepending a 'self.' in the method name definition. That will centralize the behaviour in your class and avoid some responsability issues. If you stick to this approach, remember that you **must** consider the possibility of generating the same username twice. That happens because there might be a while between you generate the username and you persist it. Never forget validating that at some point.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I hadn't learned that yet, I think I got it working but I cant tell yet since I'm getting another error in my controller now... it be awesome if you could take a look but thanks for your help either way!

Comment: You're welcome! Just keep practising! I know Rails world can be overwhelming and frustrating several times for most beginners. As a personal recommendation, I suggest having a strong Ruby base knowledge.